# HP Laser Jet Pro P1102 shared from Winows 7 Pro

Tags: printing, samba

I have trouble with this printer shared from Windows 7 Pro.
Win machine IP: 10.0.0.120
Printer URI smb://10.0.0.120/HP1102
Whenever I try to print over network I got this error:
`Bezczynna - /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups failed`. I tried installing HPLIP from here:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102.html
but it seems to doesnt work. HP-setup also doesn't support SAMBA.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this was quite obvious...
For Ubuntu 12.04 and printer HP Laser Jet Pro P1102 over network. You need to:
download and install HPLIP
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102.html
Add in system settings -> printing add new printer. And when the "select drivers" dialog appear chose HP -> LaserJet Pro P1102 (not proffesional) the driver there is `Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2` Thats it.
Happy Printing...

Comment: Thank you, Fih. This is an amazing situation. I had this problem, and was scratching my head. I read your answer, went to System->Printers->Settings, change driver, and specified: "Laserjet Pro p1102" instead of: "Laserjet Professional p1102" - works fine. Many thanks - Helen

Answer (score 0):

[`hplip` doesn't support samba](http://hplipopensource.com/node/272) but it does suggest that you should be able to add it through CUPS.

1. Open the CUPS printing admin (`http://localhost:631/admin/` or use the graphical version)
2. Add a printer in the following format (see `http://localhost:631/help/network.html`):

   ```
   smb://host/printer
   ```

   Where `host` is the netbios name or IP of the Windows computer hosting the printer.
3. It'll probably ask you for the right PPD and at that point you should be able to specify the right version from the hplip package. The interface usually manages to guess pretty close on its own.

Comment: HPLIP provide no PPD file. I wrote it... when I add printer like you say I should - in GUI - I cannot print because I get error message: `Bezczynna - /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups failed`